# Python: Find out most frequent locations on a set of gps coordinates

Tags: python, geolocation, gps

I need to analyze a set of GPS coordinates in python. I need to find out what is the most frequent location. Given precision issues of the GPS data, the precision of the locations is not very high. Difficult to explan (and to search for infos on google), therefore an example:

- I drive from home to work every day for 2 months
- I start my gps logger for each trip and stop at the end of the trip
- Occasionally, I go somewhere else

If I run the script I need to analyse the coordinates where drives started and stopped, with a location radius precision of let's say 20m, I'll find out that the most frequent place is my home and my work (each with a radius of 20m). It does not matter where did I park within this radius.

Is there any library in python that can perform such operations? What do you recommend?

Thanks

Comment: In order to reduce precision, I would just drop the last couple digits.

Comment: It's pretty simple to calculate the distance between 2 points based on lat/long... It's  Pythagoras's Theorem stuff. Given your relatively small number of coordinates (start and stop only) just do some simple maths no need for a library.

Comment: @Endophage ... I see, no need to take the earth curvature into consideration?

Comment: Not when you're only interested in 20m proximity...

Comment: @Endophage ok, so I loop for every point and calculate the distance to all others, and count how many points are less than 20m. Then, I find out which point has the most points near it. easy.

Comment: How about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_algorithm or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN ?

Comment: @otmezger yep. Additionally a small optimization, if you use square 20m proximity rather than a circle's radius, the calculation is cheaper: `diff_x < 20 and diff_y < 20` rather than `sqrt(diff_x**2 + diff_y**2) < 20`

Comment: @Endphage your solutions have O(N*N), that does not work well for big data sets.

Answer (score 1):

If you're mostly interested in the places you go, you might consider from each drive taking the first and last points, and only take intermediate points if you're there for more than *x* time. Perhaps if your average speed at that point over the last *k* datapoints is less than some threshold. That should make it much easier to apply some clustering technique (like [k-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)).

Something that may come in handy is using [approximate nearest neighbors](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/) to find for any given point the collection of points that are relatively near it.

To take a page from graphics, you might even try superimposing a fine-resolution grid over the space of all data points, and for each point make a splat of a small radius onto this grid. Every time you add a splat, you can accumulate the time you spent at that point and then keep track as you go of the points in the grid with the most accumulated time.

Answer (score 0):

For counting most frequent locations, a simple approach is to use only the first 3 digits after the latitdue/longitude decimal point, or better round to 3 digits after comma.

At aequator:

4 digits: 11 m
3 digits  111m
2 digits 1.1km
1 digits 11.1km
0 digits 111.111 km (distance between two meridians):  40 000 000 / 360

Then you could use as hashtable, multiply with e,g 1000 to get rid of the 3 decimal points, 
and store as java.awt.Point in the hashtable.

There are better solutions, but this gives an first idea.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea, because if I have a point between 2 "4 digits", it get's rounded wrong

Comment: a point which is located on a border of that 3 digit grid can fall in the other grid. But on a 60m - 100m raster thats ok, Then in worst case if your parking place varies, you have two hot spots around your home. All other solutions needs high special geospatial knowledge knowledge. (E.g use a PMR-quadtree, etc.) You might  read  Hana Samet: Foundations of Multidimensional and Metric Search structures.

Comment: Update the answer, to round to 3 digits. (Think of the soultion like a chess board, and your track you drive, like bread crumbs, you increase the counte rof each chess borad field when a bread crumb is located on it.)